# SAS ods html output getting black box instead of plots

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I'm attempting to generate plots using PROC SGRENDER within a for loop. Upon running the code in Job execution, I encounter black boxes instead of plots. When I copy the link from Job submission into the browser, I receive the same output.

These plots are meant to be displayed in an application where no parameter selection is required. I'm using SAS Viya 3.5

```
filename cd ".";
ods select all;
ods preferences;
ods html5 options(svg_mode="inline");
ods graphics /outputfmt=svg;

ods html5 (id=web) style=daisy path=cd
                          file='test';

%macro CreatePlots;
%local model i;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&modelid_list.,%str( )));
    %LET model = %scan(&modelid_list., &i.,%str( ));
    %put &=model;

    PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    SELECT distinct Name into :ShortName
        FROM PlotData WHERE modelID=&model.;
    QUIT;


PROC TEMPLATE;
   DEFINE STATGRAPH ArrowPlot;
      BEGINGRAPH ;
        ENTRYTITLE "Model: &ShortName.    ";


        LAYOUT OVERLAY /  WALLDISPLAY=(FILL) XAXISOPTS=(DISPLAY=NONE 
                LINEAROPTS=(VIEWMIN=-0.05 VIEWMAX=1.05)) YAXISOPTS=(DISPLAY=NONE LINEAROPTS=(VIEWMIN=-0.6 VIEWMAX=3));

            POLYGONPLOT X=x Y=y ID=Id / COLORRESPONSE=Sign COLORMODEL=(lightblue Pink) 
                DISPLAY=(OUTLINE FILL) OUTLINEATTRS=(COLOR=white /*white on regular screen*/ THICKNESS=2px);
        ENDLAYOUT;
      ENDGRAPH;
   END;
RUN;
    PROC SGRENDER DATA=PlotData(where=(modelID=&model.)) TEMPLATE=ArrowPlot;
RUN;

%end;
%mend CreatePlots;
%CreatePlots;

ods html5 close;
ods listing
```

In the browser, if I choose to 'Save as' (HTML) this output and open the saved file again in the browser, I obtain the correct output with all the plots.

Comment: I don't have Viya, so can't really help.  But curious if you add `PROC PRINT data=sashelp.class;run;` do you see those results?    Just wondering if the problem is specific to images.  Your last sentence is a shocker.  If it works when you download the HTML file, then it's not an ODS problem.  How are you viewing the results when you see the black box?  Some sort of web app viya interface?